# Eclipse PyDev : using environment variables to share Workspace between computers

Tags: eclipse, virtualenv, pydev

I have an Eclipse PyDev project (Eclipse 4.7.3a). I want to be able to sync the Eclipse workspace between several computers (and that it works, obviously).

First problem : the Python virtual environment. I have installed it in a folder that is located next to the Eclipse workspace (but not inside it) and is also synced between the various computers.

Since the folders for the workspace and the Python virtualenv are not located at the same point the of file system (I use Linux), my guess the simplest way to achieve this would be to use some kind of environment variable, different on each computer, that would point to the directory that contains all the synced folders.

So how can I set a Python virtualenv using a kind of system environment variable ?

Or is there another way to achieve my goal (sharing and syncing an Eclipse workspace between several computers) ?

Comment: All computers should refer to the shared path, webdav, smb or whatever.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not really help. Being obliged to locate the files exactly at the same place on each computer is what I try to avoid.

Comment: From the [reference guide](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#configuration): `export VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=/opt/python-3.3/bin/python`. Something like that? The exported var should be available from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible.

The workspace has information which is dependent on the absolute paths and is not really shareable (unless you have a mirror in both computers with files in the same paths on both).

Some configurations can be saved in the project itself or in the user settings (the ones that can do that have buttons in the preferences page to save to a project / show from a project -- but note that the interpreter itself still doesn't have that).

Personally, what I do is save everything possible in the project and commit that to git (so, anyone using the project will use those same settings), and try to use the same paths on multiple machines.